# There is no download option neither in Edge nor in Chrome for my audio

Tags: html, html5-video, html5-audio

I am trying to download audio. I have my code as below and I everything is okay but download is not working.

```
<audio controls autoplay>
            <source src="audio/OneRepublic%20-%20Good%20Life%20128k%20m4a).m4a" type="audio/mp4">
            <source src="audio/OneRepublic%20-%20Good%20Life%20128k%20mp3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            <source src="audio/OneRepublic%20-%20Good%20Life%20128k%20ogg.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
            <source src="audio/OneRepublic%20-%20Good%20Life%20128k%20wav.wav" type="audio/wav">
            Your browser is not supporting any audio formats. 
        </audio>
        <p>To download mp3 <a href="audio/OneRepublic%20-%20Good%20Life%20128k%20mp3.mp3">click here</a></p>
```

I tried this as well, still didn't worked.

```
<p>To download mp3 <a href="../audio/OneRepublic%20-%20Good%20Life%20128k%20mp3.mp3" download>click here</a></p>
```

When I am clicking in 'click here' I am getting this only in both browsers.
I tried to download video as well and facing the same problem.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

downloading a file full depends on your server but right now you are accessing local file try to run this code on server
for local use http-server

I had tried and I am able to see the download button for the local files too
in the below screenshot I had added 4 audio

1. with server allowing download
2. with server not allowing download
3. local file
4. file on my firebase cloud

so you need to run it on a local server I had runned it using http-server and It showed me the download icon.
try using it if you have [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) or any other server.

[image]

Comment: Try to [paste testable HTML code](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67716305/edit) (actual text) and not an image. It's possible you have a correct answer but asker cannot confirm by testing a PNG image as HTML...